# How to efficiently store matmul results into another matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, performance, eigen, matrix-multiplication

I would like to store multiple matmul results as row vector into another matrix, but my current code seems to take a lot of memory space. Here is my pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < C_row; ++i) {
  C.row(i) = (A.transpose() * B).reshaped(1, C_col);
}
```

In this case, C is actually a Map of pre-allocated array declared as `Map<Matrix<float, -1, -1, RowMajor>> C(C_array, C_row, C_col);`.
Therefore, I expect the calculated matmul results can directly go to memory space of C and do not create temporary copies. In other words, the total memory usage should be the same with or without the above code. But I found that with the above code, the memory usage is increased significantly.

I tried to use `C.row(i).noalias()` to directly assign results to each row of C, but there is no memory usage difference. How to make this code more efficiently by taking less memory space?

Comment: You're storing into a matrix C.  The memory usage at the end should be the memory used by C.  Where do you think that you can save memory?  It would help if you can describe in words, perhaps using numbers such as "My current solution consumes 4.6 MB of memory but C is only 32x100 doubles which should be 25 kB."  You should also include real code, not pseudocode with missing declarations like the type of C.

Comment: As John said, please [edit] your question to include actual working code. Could you also clarify if `A` and `B` are the same in every loop iteration? Or if they are different, are you able to store them (the different `A[i]`, `B[i]` matrices) in one matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reshaped` is the culprit. It cannot be folded into the matrix multiplication so it results in a temporary allocation for the multiplication. Ideally you would need to put it onto the left of the assignment:

```
C.row(i).reshaped(A.cols(), B.cols()).noalias() = A.transpose() * B;
```

However, that does not compile. `Reshaped` doesn't seem to fulfil the required interface. It's a pretty new addition to Eigen, so I'm not overly surprised. You might want to open a feature request on their bug tracker.

Anyway, as a workaround, try this:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> reshaped(C.row(i).data(), A.cols(), B.cols());
reshaped.noalias() = A.transpose() * B;
```

Comment: An alternative would be to create the `C` Map with size `A.cols()*C_row` times `B.cols()`, access that using blocks and only reshape it to `C_row` times `A.cols()*B.cols()` at the end (or create a different `Map` for that).